# Understanding the scope of code evoked in the Java Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to understand which events will be managed from an event disptach thread (EDT).

Let's assume something simple, a simple piece of code that simple opens a JOptionPane, waits for the user's response, then closes it.    What events related to this object are now put on the EDT?   Is it:
a) Just the creation of the object (the JOptionPane).
b) All object related events for the lifetime of the object.
C) Something else (please specify).

Thank you,

Elliott

See below:

```
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myComponent, msg);
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The JOptionPane example may not be the best since it's only a one line deal, all of which should be done on the EDT.

Comment: I have written (bad) code where JOptionPanes have been invoked off the EDT so it is not that unrealistic.

Comment: Oh, I agree that JOptionPane needs to be called on the EDT as I noted above.

Comment: regarding the second part of your question: I would assume that all Swing code needs to be called on the EDT unless the API states that it is thread safe. So if you are going to be extracting text from a JTextField held in the component held by the JOptionPane, you should call getText() on the JTextField on the EDT.

Comment: Yeah.   It is just a simple example.    I am more interested in understanding the scope of events that are covered (that are placed on the EDT).   Is it just the creation of the Swing Object or is it also all the events that occur when that Swing Object (in this case a JOptionPane) exits (e.g. button presses, the object closing, etc.).

Comment: Code executed from within a listener is automatically executed on the EDT.

Comment: Does this include the disposal (closing) of the object?

Comment: If you mean garbage collection, this is completely unrelated and for Java not something that we have to worry about directly. If you mean calling dispose() on a Swing resource, then yes, I'd call that on the EDT unless the API states it is thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can remember, all the following "events" will be executed in the EDT:

- all events directly triggered by the end user (mouse events, key events) and all higher-level events triggered by these (action, focus...); actually you could say that all AWT and Swing EventListeners are always called in the EDT
- all painting code (as triggered by changes in components or changes in widows size or positions, whenver an area needs to be painted)
- any code called through `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Answer (score 1):

All [`JOptionPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) dialogs are modal: they block user-generated input events to other windows, but the [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) continues to process events for all windows. In this [`DialogTest`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/d95da1f8f9af2339), the animation continues while `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` awaits input.  There's a related discussion [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_thread/thread/c7c24ba55c45933a).